# NoSQL injections with Dynogels

Tags: sql-injection, dynogels

Does anyone know how effective the `Dynogels` component would be at helping to prevent a NO SQL injection attack going through to a Dynamo DB back-end?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ExpressionAttributeValues` as shown here? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.ReadData.Query.html

Comment: that looks very interesting, will give that a look over.  Thanks.